# LUKS encryption using passphrase + TPM

Tags: linux, luks, secure-boot, tpm, ftpm

I have questions about secure boot and TPMs and I couldn’t find precise answers on the web, so I’m hoping someone skilled in this domain will be able to answer.

In a case of an evil maid attack, what prevents an attacker from replacing the chip containing the keys used for verification of the booted OS with a rogue one, allowing to boot a rogue OS ?

Assuming that nothing really prevents that, how can I configure LUKS so that it unlocks only if there is the right TPM module **plus** a manually-entered password ?
So I’m protected against chip replacement **and** cold-boot attack/bus-sniffing, because the system can only boot with the presence of the original TPM **and** myself.

I’m sorry if I asked something evident, don’t exactly know how all of this is working.

Comment: Are you really asking about a scenario where someone physically desolders a chip and solders a new one?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m talking about. I know this might sound a bit paranoid, but my question was more about knowing more about security and what is possible to do, and eventually applying that to my computer if the process isn’t too difficult. As we say, in terms of security, we should always imagine the worst case scenario.

EDIT : By the way, I didn’t think about that earlier, but an attacker won’t necessarily have to desolder, he could replace the entire motherboard with a same looking one and move the drive(s) to the attacker-controlled motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the TPM to store the keys used for unlocking a LUKS volume, then removing/replacing that TPM will automatically force the OS to require a password to unlock, as it no longer has the keys available.

If you really want luks to require both TPM keys and a password on every unlock, then you will need to double-encrypt your volume

Comment: I knew that storing the keys in the TPM make it’s presence necessary for the LUKS to decrypt, but this is vulnerable to (AFAIK) cold boot and bus sniffing attacks. That’s why I think about combining this with a manually-entered keyboard.

The double encryption is interesting, but a more optimal setup might be possible, I was thinking about something like decrypting the TPM key with a passphrase, which in turns decrypts the disk.